# Is it best to move a poorly-performing website to a new domain name upon a major update?

Tags: seo, domains

My rationale is since my site was poorly received, it will be better to get a clean state. There are many instances of bad user experience with the current site, related to slow loading and unresponsiveness. A new update is on the way that basically fixes all those concerns.
The site is almost a year old and has less than 200 visits. The new version is way more performant so should I stick with the old domain name or get a new one for the update?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the content has more to do with this than the domain name.

Quote from John Mueller -

> Finally, in 2020, Google Webmaster Trends Analyst John Mueller revealed keywords in domain names no longer play a role in determining search engine results rankings.
>
> Answering a question if keywords in domain names impact rankings during an Ask Google Webmasters video, he said, “In short, no. You don’t get a special bonus like that from having a keyword in your top-level domain.”

From [Is Domain Name A Google Ranking Factor?](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/ranking-factors/domain-name/)

Here's another

> **Does domain name affect Google search?**
> The domain extension, commonly referred to as the Top-Level Domain (TLD), generally isn’t considered a Google ranking factor, except in the area of International SEO. In this case, having a specific country code top-level domains (ccTLDs) can indicate to search engines which country your content is targeted at.

From [Does domain name affect Google search?](https://profound-information.com/does-domain-name-affect-google-search/)

Comment: The old website was very buggy and slow i fear that when I roolout the update it may still have a poor ranking is it a reasonable concern?

Comment: A new website (domain name) will take a while to get ranked.  First Google will have to trust your site.  Your old site is already trusted.  Even if it's slow and buggy.  Google will rescan and act according to the new content.